# Error al abrir conexión a Excel (OleDbConnection) VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

Tengo un método con una conexión a un archivo **Excel** del cual debo sacar unos datos, al ejecutar el método la primera vez funciona sin problemas, pero si lo quiero ejecutar la segunda vez me tira un error al abrir la conexión, el problema es que es un error genérico "Un componente externo produjo una excepción" sin algún código para buscar solución. Me encargué de cerrar bien la conexión la primera vez que se ejecuta el método (incluso usé un **connection.Dispose()**) pero aún sigue con error. Otra cosa que pasa es que si cierro **Visual Studio** y lo abro, puedo conectarme una vez pero no la segunda

```
    Try

        Select Case Extension
            Case ".xls"
                'Excel 97-03
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel03ConString").ConnectionString
                Exit Select
            Case ".xlsx"
                'Excel 07
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07ConString").ConnectionString
                Exit Select
        End Select
        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR)

        connExcel = New OleDbConnection(conStr)
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
        'Get the name of First Sheet

        If (connExcel.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            connExcel.Open()
        End If

        Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
        Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()

        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" & SheetName & "]"
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel
        oda.Fill(dt)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New System.Exception(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connExcel.Close()
        connExcel.Dispose()
        cmdExcel.Dispose()
        oda.Dispose()

    End Try
    Return dt
```

Comment: Me pasa el mismo problema, aun no encentro solucion...

Answer (score 1):

encontré la solución, era la versión del "Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components", había una versión mas nueva en el servidor pero antes funcionaba con la 2007 así que instalé esa nuevamente y funcionó, también el formato del excel se pasó a "2003" y no hubo ningún problema